# Apply a function to every element in a list to every element in another list - Haskell

Tags: haskell, ghci

My ultimate goal is to find if a list y contains all the elements of list x (I'm checking if x is a subset of y sort of thing)

```
subset x y =
and [out | z <- x
         , out <- filter (==z) y ]
```

This doesn't work, and I know it's because z is a list still. I'm trying to make sense of this.

I think I may have to use the `elem` function, but I'm not sure how to split x into chars that I can compare separately through y.

I'm ashamed to say that I've been working on this simple problem for an hour and a half.

Comment: "because `z` is a list still" – er, no, it's not; `y` and `out` are lists. — The code you provided isn't syntactically right (missing comma, indentation); please correct that so we can help you best.

Comment: If the elements are `Ord`, you can do this much more efficiently. Can you see how?

Answer (score 3):

Checking whether all elements of `xs` are elements of `ys` is very straightforward. Loop through `xs`, and for each element, check if it is in `ys`:

```
subset xs ys = all (\x -> elem x ys) xs
```

Comment: you can also use infix syntax: `subset xs ys = all (\`elem\` ys) xs`

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the list difference function (`\\`). If you have list y and list x, and you want to check that all elements of x are in y, then `x \\ y` will return a new list with the elements of x that are not in y. If all the elements of x are in y, the returned list will be empty.

For example, if your list y is [1,2,3,4,5] and your list x is [2,4], you can do:

```
Prelude> [2,4] \\ [1,2,3,4,5]
[]
```

If list y is [1,2,3,4,5] and list x is [2,4,6], then:

```
Prelude> [2,4,6] \\ [1,2,3,4,5]
[6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to reason about subsets is to use sets as the data type.

```
import qualified Data.Set as S

subset :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
subset xs ys = S.isSubsetOf (S.fromList xs) (S.fromList ys)
```

Then it's as simple as:

```
*Main> subset [1..5] [1..10]
True
*Main> subset [0..5] [1..10]
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's break this down into two subproblems:

1. Find if a *value* is a member of a list;
2. Use the solution to #1 to test whether *every* value in a list is in the second one.

For the first subproblem there is a library function already:

```
elem :: (Eq a, Foldable t) => a -> t a -> Bool
```

Lists are a `Foldable` type, so you can use this function with lists for `t` and it would have the following type:

```
elem :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Bool
```

**EXERCISE:** Write your own version of `elem`, specialized to work with lists (don't worry about the `Foldable` stuff now).

So now, to tackle #2, one first step would be this:

```
-- For each element of `xs`, test whether it's an element of `ys`.
-- Return a list of the results.
notYetSubset :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [Bool]
notYetSubset xs ys = map (\x -> elem x ys) xs
```

After that, we need to go from the list of individual boolean results to just one boolean.  There's a standard library function that does that as well:

```
-- Return true if and only if every element of the argument collection is 
-- is true.
and :: Foldable t => t Bool -> Bool
```

**EXERCISE:** write your own version of `and`, specialized to lists:

```
myAnd :: [Bool] -> Bool
myAnd [] = _fillMeIn
myAnd (x:xs) = _fillMeIn
```

With these tools, now we can write `subset`:

```
subset :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [Bool]
subset xs ys = and (map (\x -> elem x ys) xs)
```

Although a more experienced Haskeller would probably write it like this:

```
subset :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [Bool]
subset xs ys = every (`elem` ys) xs

{- This:

       (`elem` ys)

   ...is a syntactic shortcut for this:

       \x -> x elem ys
-}
```

...where `every` is another standard library function that is just a shortcut for the combination of `map` and `and`:

```
-- Apply a boolean test to every element of the list, and
-- return `True` if and only if the test succeeds for all elements.
every :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
every p = and . map p
```